# Postgres: Replicating over ssh at specific time frames

Tags: ssh, postgresql, replication

Can someone help me with the most **common stable replication mechanism** for postgres that I can run at specific times of a day(know it sounds weird) postgres that can run over ssh?

Over ssh is because my machines are on linode with only one network interface – public and I don’t want to expose the port

Comment: Do you mean that you have a second postgres server on which you want updated data from the main server to be loaded at specific times, or do you just want a backup to be stored somewhere so it can be re-loaded when necessary?

Comment: @JennyD yes, I have another machine running which needs the data from the primary machine and not a backup

Answer (score 4):

I use a script started from crontab: this script creates a ssh tunnel to the remote postgres host, starts a session to the remote postgres database using the local psql binary, then kills the tunnel once done.

For example:

```
# $REMOTE is the hostname of the remote postgres server
# this tunnel maps the local port 50432 to the remote port 5432 where the
#  remote postgres instance is listening
/usr/bin/ssh -nNT postgres@${REMOTE} -L 50432:localhost:5432 &
TUNNELPID=$!

# wait a little for the tunnel to establish itself
sleep 5

# execute the statements in load.sql against the remote database 'remotepgdb'
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -q -h localhost -p 50432 -U remotepguser remotepgdb < ${SCRIPT_PATH}/load.sql

# kill the ssh tunnel
/usr/bin/kill ${TUNNELPID}
```

Before trying this technique, I suggest to make sure that the local psql client and the remote postgres database are exactly at the same version.

Comment: This is the right direction. Let me try this out.

Comment: I see that you have loading `${SCRIPT_PATH}/load.sql`. Is there a way to directly pull from the local db, imitating replication? Without locks and all..

Comment: You may want to investigate if dblink http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-function.html fits your requirement. You could keep the ssh tunnel and write a stored procedure on the local db which opens a connection to the remote db and manipulates the data. See also http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/44-guid.html for examples of using dblink.

Answer (score 2):

You could also have a look at [pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page). We use it for continous replication of a postgres database, and if you keep an ssh-tunnel (or stunnel) up, you can have the data encrypted during transfer